# Aligning the dynamic form elements added on selection box event to the top of the page one after the another above the selection box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not able to align the dynamic form elements added on selection box event to the top of the page one after the another. It shoul de added above the selection box and the selection box should automatically shifts downwards. But my code added the elements downwords overlapping to the selection box.

```js
  function addToFilter(divName)
  {
   var val= document.getElementById('filter').value;
   var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
   switch(val)
   {
    case 'mcus': 
    newdiv.innerHTML = "Type&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:<select id='mcuc_selection'><option value='select'>--select--</option><option value='a1'>A1</option><option value='m1'>M1</option><option value='n1'>N1</option></select>";
    break;
    case 'oc': 
    newdiv.innerHTML = "Type&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:<select id='oc_selection'><option value='select'>--select--</option><option value='a2'>A2</option><option value='m2'>M2</option><option value='n2'>N2</option></select>";
    break;
   }
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <div class="x_panel">
          <div class="x_title">
          
           <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
            <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
            </li>
           </ul>
           <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>     
          <div id ="flt" class="x_content"><br><br>
           <div id="div_filter">
            Add Filters&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:
            <select id="filter">
             <option value="select">--select--</option>
             <option value="mcus">A</option>
             <option value="oc">B</option>
            </select>
            <img id="add-icon" src="add-icon.png" alt="add" onclick="addToFilter('flt');">
            <button id="go" type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-left: 185%; width:14%">Go</button>
           </div>
           <br>          
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `insertBefore` to prepend elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

```js
function addToFilter(divName) {
  var val = document.getElementById('filter').value;
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  switch (val) {
    case 'mcus':
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Type&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:<select id='mcuc_selection'><option value='select'>--select--</option><option value='a1'>A1</option><option value='m1'>M1</option><option value='n1'>N1</option></select>";
      break;
    case 'oc':
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Type&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:<select id='oc_selection'><option value='select'>--select--</option><option value='a2'>A2</option><option value='m2'>M2</option><option value='n2'>N2</option></select>";
      break;
  }
  var ParentNode = document.getElementById(divName);
  var theFirstChild = ParentNode.firstChild;
  ParentNode.insertBefore(newdiv, theFirstChild);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="x_panel">
    <div class="x_title">

      <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
        <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="flt" class="x_content">
      <br>
      <br>
      <div id="div_filter">
        Add Filters&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:
        <select id="filter">
          <option value="select">--select--</option>
          <option value="mcus">A</option>
          <option value="oc">B</option>
        </select>
        <img id="add-icon" src="add-icon.png" alt="add" onclick="addToFilter('flt');">
        <button id="go" type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-left: 185%; width:14%">Go</button>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```